# python get second element from tuple after counting duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have got a list consisting of tuples like this:

```
[('25', 'title_1'), ('30', 'title_2'), ('55', 'title_3'), ('60', 'title_4'), ('25', 'title_5'), ('55', 'title_6')]
```

Now I'd like to filter for duplicates using a Counter like this:

```
count = collections.Counter([x for (x, y) in schedule])

for element in count.items():
    if element[1] > 1:
        print('Scheduled:', element[0], 'Count:', element[1])
```

Output:

```
Scheduled: 25 Count: 2
Scheduled: 55 Count: 2
```

Next step I would need would be to get the "Title" from these duplicates, how can I achieve this? I was thinking about modifying the Counter but I don't know how. I tried this:

`count = collections.Counter([(x, y) for (x, y) in schedule])`

but by doing this each of the tuples would be count=1

My desired goal would be to have a  list with only the duplicates + titles:

```
[('25', 'title_1'), ('55', 'title_3'), ('25', 'title_5'), ('55', 'title_6')]
```

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can

- create a set of duplicated "numbers" from the Counter

  - in your example, `{'25', '55'}`
- iterate through your list, appending it to a new one if the number occurs in your set of duplicate numbers.

e.g.

```
duplicated_numbers = ...
list_of_duplicates = []
for item in list_of_items:
  if item[0] in duplicated_numbers:
    list_of_duplicates.append(item)
```